# JavaScript Prompt Validation for Integer Input

Tags: javascript, validation, prompt

I found myself needing to create a function to validate the input of a JS prompt as an integer. It turns out there is a little subtlety involved as pressing `cancel` returns `null.`

What I originally tried (ported from a Python program) was:

```
function getInteger() {
    let number = null
    while ( number == null ) {
        let value = prompt( "Guess number: " )
        if ( isNaN( value ) ) {
            alert( "Invalid input." )
        } else {
            number = parseInt( value )
        }
    }
    return number;
}
```

However, this returns `NaN` if I cancel the prompt, which doesn't make sense as a return value (it seems `isNaN(null)`returns `false`). (By doesn't make sense, I mean "can't be meaningfully used by the rest of the program as it's not descriptive of what happened").

So after some thought, I came up with:

```
function getInteger(){
    while(true){
        let input = prompt("Input number: ");
        if (input && isNaN( input ) ) {
            // user pressed OK, but input invalid
            alert("Invalid input.");
        } else if (input) {
            // user typed something valid and hit OK
            return parseInt(input);
        } else {
            // User pressed cancel
            alert("I'm out of here.")
            return;
        }
    }
}

getInteger()
```

I'm curious as to whether I've covered all possible inputs? Also, whether my code is "well written" - is there a better way to do it? Is using `while(true)` considered a bad idea?

I'm aware that prompts in general are probably a bad idea, but that's not the point here.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Can't answer about this `prompt` function behavior, but your last code is equivalent to:

```
let input;
while (input = prompt("Input number: ")) {
  if (isNaN(input)) {
    alert("Invalid input.");
  } else {
    return parseInt(input);
  }
}
```

Still outside the `prompt` behavior stuff, if you expect an integer (i.e. *only* figures) in your `input` string, I would tend to test this with a regular expression like `/^\d+$/`, instead of `isNaN` (what if I input `"1.25"`? Result wouldn't be `NaN`, and it'd `return 1`, but it doesn't seem to be what you intend to achieve).

**EDIT** the code is not *exactly* equivalent, so let's make it so:

```
let input;
while (input = prompt("Input number: ")) {
  if (isNaN(input)) {
    alert("Invalid input.");
  } else {
    return parseInt(input);
  }
}
alert("I'm out of here.");
return;
```

Comment: I'm not sure your code is equivalent. It doesn't handle the user clicking cancel which returns `null`.  `isNan(null)` returns `false`.

Comment: Oh indeed, it does not `alert("I'm outta here");`, the _falsy_ case is handled directly by the `while` (if `input` is falsy, then the `while` breaks).

Answer (score 2):

I run your code above, i try to input nothing and press OK and its show alert like i cancel the prompt. I think you should check also whether user input something or nothing. Your code might be looks like this:

```js
function getInteger(){
    while(true){      
        let input = prompt("Input number: ");
        
        if (input == null) {
            // user hit cancel
          alert("I'm out of here.")
            return true;
        } else{
           if (input.length<=0 || isNaN( input ) ) {
                // user pressed OK, but input invalid or does not input anything
                alert("Invalid input.");
            } else {
                // user typed something valid and hit OK
                return parseInt(input);
            }
         }                    
        }                     
}

getInteger()
```

Comment: That's a good point.I think changing my first condition to `if (input == "" || isNaN( input ) ) {` also fixes it. The function seems surprisingly complex for something so simple though.

Comment: That wouldn't have happened using a regular expression instead of `isNaN`... just sayin'! ;)